# Cant post from input form into javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, post

Hi i'm having a problem with posting from the input "searchtag" into "hash:'searchTag'" inside the javascript array. Please help me out! I'm very new to Javascript.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="searchTag" placeholder="Search">
<input class="submit" name="Search" type="submit">

<div class="instagram"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(".instagram").instagram({
            hash:'searchTag',
            clientId: 'My-clientId',
            image_size:'tumbnail'
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: look at onchange event, them get the value of the input and you will have the trick ;)

Comment: use `$(document).ready(function() { //code here javascript });`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to collect the value from `searchTag`, which I assume you'll want to do when clicking the search button. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#SearchButton').click(function () {
        var searchTag = $('#SearchTagInput').val();

        $(".instagram").instagram({
            hash: searchTag,
            clientId: 'My-clientId',
            image_size:'tumbnail'
        });
    });
});
```

The above example requires that you add the corresponding ids, `SearchButton` and `SearchTagInput`, to the input fields.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38zKb/) for an example.

Comment: It worked but now if i want to search for a new tag i have to reload the site so i can search agian otherwise it wont update

Comment: try to empty the collection first